# How can I call node id in template file?

Tags: nodes, 7

Using Drupal 7.

I have a `page--front.tpl.php` template file. And I want import a node in this file.

How can I do it?

Comment: What will your node id be of ? the current node ? an arbitrary node ? id from parameter ?

Comment: I want to show a spesific node id.

Comment: simplest and ugliest you could use node_load($your_id)

Comment: a cleaner posibility would be to use the node_block module.

Comment: or else you could use a view to choose the content to display... 

You choice will depend on plenty of things : will your node change, who decides and changes de selected note  to display, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
<?php
$view_mode = 'teaser'; // Or 'full' for example

$node = node_load(2);

$view = node_view($node, $view_mode);

print render($view);
?>
```

Comment: this will work but it's not recommended, for security reasons, you have to use blocks.

Comment: How this code carries a risk?